# Oracle SQL - Summarize Multiple Levels for One Score Column Based on One Column Being Unique

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return the SUM and SAMPLE SIZE of a "Score" column at multiple summary levels for individual "Patients". The issue is that as I add summary levels, some of those summary levels split the one row per patient into multiple rows per patients. As these patients are split out, the SUM of the Summary Levels begin to be inaccurate. Is there some way to use one Subquery with multiple rows per "Patient", but only Group By/SUM at each level WHERE "Patient" is UNIQUE?

Example SubQuery Results:

```
Patient Location    DiseaseState    Care Team Member    Score
1       CityA       Hypertension    Provider1       10
1       CityA       Hypertension    Pharmacist1     10
1       CityA       Hypertension    Health Coach1   10
1       CityA       Diabetes        Provider1       10
1       CityA       Diabetes        Pharmacist1     10
1       CityA       Diabetes        Health Coach1   10
2       CityB       Hypertension    Provider1       20
2       CityB       Hypertension    Pharmacist2     20
2       CityB       Hypertension    Health Coach1   20
2       CityB       Diabetes        Provider1       20
2       CityB       Diabetes        Pharmacist2     20
2       CityB       Diabetes        Health Coach1   20
2       CityB       CKD             Provider1       20
2       CityB       CKD             Pharmacist2     20
2       CityB       CKD             Health Coach1   20
```

What I would like to summarize from this Subquery is Average scores by each "Care Team Member", "DiseaseState", "Location". If I SUM "Score" By "Care Team Member", I get a much higher score than I should. Can I somehow SUM "Score" WHERE "Patient" is UNIQUE and GROUP BY "Location", "DiseaseState", "Care Team Member", etc.?

Comment: So the data you show is the data your query selects now. But you want to condense this data somehow. Can you please show the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a PARTITION with the SUM analytics function. Something like :

```
SELECT SUM(SCORE) OVER (PARTITION BY "Location", "DiseaseState", "Care Team Member")
FROM TABLE
```

The partition clause acts like a `group by`, only summing the values for each group, but doesn't require you to modify the existing `group by` clause

The following link has some additional information and examples using SUM as an analytic function
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115

Comment: This will not aggregate any rows of the sample data as each row has a unique combination of location, disease state and care team member.

Comment: @MT0, you may be right. However, not having access to the query he's using, it's hard to be more specific about exactly how to use the analytics function. I've personally accomplished similar requirements using this method though. The partition may need to be run on a lower level of the original query to get the desired results, but without knowing how the data is generated it's impossible to be more precise.